# Define upper limit of file size

Tags: java, filesize

I am developing an Web based compiler.For this I need to save the Input that must be passed to   a source code in a file and then save the output genereated in a file.I want to limit the file size of the output file to max value .
here is the code snippet :

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir + "/run.sh")));
            out.write("cd \"" + dir +"\"\n");
            out.write("chroot .\n");
            out.write("./a.out < in.txt > out.txt");
            out.close();
```

how do i define an upper limit to the file size?

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: By the way, this code looks highly vulnerable to injection... for example, what if there's a directory called `"; rm -rf .; echo "`?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `ulimit -f` to restrict the total file output size.

Another possibility would be to pipe the output through `dd bs=1 count=NNNNNN`

---

By the way, you don't need to run a shell script that way.  You could do it like this:

```
exec(new String[]{
     "/bin/sh", "-c", 
     "cd \"" + dir + "\" ; chroot . ; ./a.out < in.txt > out.txt"
});
```

This doesn't address the "injection" security problem though.  And you *really, really* **need** to address that!!